# How to get Facebook comments count in HTML5 without using a <div>?

Tags: facebook, html, comments

The Facebook comments count can be done in three different ways: (without directly using JS)

```
<fb:comments-count href="http://example.com" />

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=example.com" />

<div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com">0</div>
```

The issue, however, is that doing something like this messes things up:

```
<p><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com">0</div> comments</p>
```

...because a `<div>` is firstly, not valid inside a `<p>` tag and secondly, looks wrong (though this could be fixed with CSS).

Basically, my question is: is there a way to do the above without using a `<div>` (a `<span>` for example), bearing in mind that I want to use the HTML5 method and (if possible!) want to avoid using javascript?

Clarification: I would like to avoid writing extra JS in the page simply because the MVC view currently looks nice and clean and I would prefer to keep it that way. Obviously, I'm still including the Facebook Connect library.

Comment: Well, have you tried it with a SPAN?

Comment: Yes, I have. It doesn't work. Facebook's documentation on <code>comments-count</code> is very minimal (that I can find, anyway). I'm hoping someone who has used it extensively might know something I can't find.

Comment: Have you considered having a DIV instead of a P as the outer element?

Comment: Does the FB Connect stuff replace the div with an iframe? I might be wrong, but it's possible that the div is removed by the JS?

Comment: Hmm... if that is the only way around it, then I shall do that. It just seems a bit odd/messy that it's so restrictive to be honest when all it is really doing is replacing a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one solution would be to use a DIV instead of a P as the outer element.

Comment: The issue is that doing `<p><div></div></p>` causes this: http://grab.by/bufI As in, the browser (Chrome does this, at least) makes one empty `<p>` then the `<div>`, then the text, then another empty `<p>`. Though as you said above, making the outer element a `<div>` also would solve that.

Comment: @JamesBillingham I think the suggestion was to remove the `<p>` tag, and use CSS to make the sole remaining `<div>` inline--no need for an outer `<div>` in that case.

Comment: @Sime Okay. Ended up doing it like this: `<div class="ptag"><div style="display: inline" class="fb-comments-count" data-href="/News/123">0</div> comments</div>`

Comment: @JamesBillingham I see. So, having a DIV inside a P breaks the structure in some browsers...

Comment: The original question said "without using a div" but here we are using a div in the accepted answer.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yeah. So I've used your above recommendation and just styled the outer `<div>` as though it was a `<p>`.

Comment: @Rob Yup, but for the specific reason (as noted in the question) that it would look wrong and that it would be invalid. Both of those points have been solved with this solution thus making the use of a `<div>` entirely acceptable.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Actually, it's simply invalid to have a `<div>` inside a `<p>`. The markup `<p><div></div>` will always, always produce the two elements as adjacent siblings, in that order. It's equivalent to `<p></p><div></div>` — the `<div>` tag implicitly closes the `<p>` just before it.

Comment: @BoltClock That was not at all what he was implying. He was actually instructing me not to do that, but rather to do `<div><div>0</div> comments</div>` instead. If you could undo the downvote (if it was you), that'd be good.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't downvote though, but the answer seems incomplete... that could have been why.